# Heroku keep crashing after Starting process with command `npm start'

Tags: node.js, facebook, heroku, facebook-messenger-bot

I am newbie. I am following Tutorial from https://www.sitepoint.com/building-facebook-chat-bot-node-heroku/ to make sample facebook messenger bot.

Just when I deployed it first time in heroku I got error

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "spbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Testbot",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "Munkh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.1",
    "request": "^2.81.0"
  }
}
```

here is app.js

```
    var express = require("express");
var request = require("request");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.listen((process.env.PORT || 5000));

// Server index page
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Deployed!");
});

// Facebook Webhook
// Used for verification
app.get("/webhook", function (req, res) {
  if (req.query["hub.verify_token"] === "this_is_my_token") {
    console.log("Verified webhook");
    res.status(200).send(req.query["hub.challenge"]);
  } else {
    console.error("Verification failed. The tokens do not match.");
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
});
```

I got error like this

```
2017-03-20T02:11:15.997279+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-03-20T02:11:17.849748+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-03-20T02:11:20.455381+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-20T02:11:20.455396+00:00 app[web.1]: > spbot@1.0.0 start /app
2017-03-20T02:11:20.455397+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2017-03-20T02:11:20.455397+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-20T02:11:20.978077+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-03-20T02:11:20.994169+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-03-20T02:11:20.994986+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-03-20T02:11:23.337790+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-03-20T02:11:27.660508+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-20T02:11:27.660527+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2017-03-20T02:11:27.660526+00:00 app[web.1]: > spbot@1.0.0 start /app
2017-03-20T02:11:27.660528+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-20T02:11:27.896343+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-03-20T02:11:27.881546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

Because error doesn't specify what went wrong and just keep crashing, I can't find a solution. My apologies if it is simple question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the node.js and npm version which you are using in package.json, as mentioned below.

Specify the versions which you are using in your development.

```
{
  "name": "spbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Testbot",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "Munkh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.1",
    "request": "^2.81.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.0.0",
    "npm": "3.10.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I still couldn't make it work with                                                   "engines": {
    "node": "7.0.0",
    "npm": "4.0.2"
  } anymore suggestions? error is same as before

Comment: @Munkh-ErdeneErdenebileg correct npm version of 7.0.0 is 3.10.8.
Check the updated code.